# Jenkins multibranch pipeline does not detect pull requests in Bitbucket server

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, bitbucket-server, jenkins-blueocean

I am having trouble getting Jenkins multibranch pipeline detect pull requests created in the Bitbucket server (private instance). I have setup the "Bitbucket server webhook to Jenkins" which is triggering the build on master, develop and feature branches except pull-requests. I have defined the build steps in Jenkisfile and can confirm the PR branch also includes the Jenkinsfile.
In the Jenkins configuration, I have enabled "Discover branches" under Branch Sources configuration

Answer (score 0):

Pull Request isn’t a branch, it is usually something that is done prior to publishing to a branch. Usually, the pull request is approved, then published to the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After multiple trial and error and google search, I have managed to get the Jenkins Multibranch pipeline work with Bitbucket server. The key was to use 'Bitbucket' (from bitbucket branch source plugin) as the Branch source. Also, I had to include a dummy trigger in my Jenkinsfile for the Jenkins webhook to work from bitbucket

`triggers {
  bitbucketPush()
  pollSCM('0 0 1 1 0')
}`